# How to persist state info within an IE-hosted ActiveX control?

Tags: .net, internet-explorer, activex

I have a .NET ActiveX control that is hosted in IE and who's interface must conform to an unchangeable client spec. The issue is I need to keep track of a single persistent value in the control across page loads (if the user goes to another page and later returns.)

Is there any way I can persist this information without having to interact with the page itself (which I cannot do) or the web server (which I can do if necessary but would prefer not to.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's less than ideal but I was able to get this working by writing/reading temporary files. I did this by getting a temporary file from the OS and serializing a `Dictionary<string, object>` into it. Everything I needed to persist I just added to the dictionary and saved it.